# jQuery How to retrieve part of information inside clicked div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="movie">
    <h2>information i need</h2>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/the-simsons.jpg" alt="the-simpsons" class="movieposter" />
    </a>
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <p>information i need</p>
    <h3>Genre</h3>
    <p>information i need</p>
    <h3>Rating</h3>
    <p>information i need</p>
</div>
```

Above is one of my divs. Once the image is clicked, I would like to retrieve the information in p tag by using jQuery. Below is my jQuery code.

```
$(".movieposter").click(function() {
    //some of my code is here already
});
```

Is there any way to retrieve information in jQuery function?

Comment: Which p tag content ? there are 3 p elements in your code

Comment: take a look at [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Do you want retrieve all p tag  text  ?

Comment: yes, i need to retrieve all p tag text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can find the parent div with `class="movie"` using `closest` and then find all `p` elements. Iterate all `p` elements and read information using `$(this).text();`

```
$(".movieposter").click(function() {
    //some of my code is here already
    $(this).closest('.movie').find('p').each(function(){
       alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2eqeL2a/21/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with this:
use  [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```
$(".movieposter").click(function() {
    //some of my code is here already
    var info = $(this).closest('.movie').find('p').map(function(){
       return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    console.log(info);
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2wg4xaL/)

Answer (score 1):

use **[map();](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** in jquery to retrieve data into array

```
 $(".movieposter").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).closest('.movie').find('p').map(function (i, node) {
        return node.innerHTML;
    }).get();
    console.log(text);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sqL17sj1/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('.movieposter').click(function(){
         $('.movie').find('p').each(function(){
             alert($(this).text());
         });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function(){
      $(".movieposter").click(function(e) {
         $(this).parents('.movie').find('p').each(function(){
           alert($(this).text());
         });
      });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ashishtest12/r2eqeL2a/23/)